# trying to re-display my menu after a second integer is put in

Tags: python, menu

guys I am a student in an intro to programming class and so I am very to programming in python.
 anyway my teacher has asked us to create an integer menu to just do basic things.

well I am having trouble getting my menu to re-display after a new integer is put in.

The program will go through the menu and then the displaymenu and then I can select 1 to go back to the menu but once I enter a new integer the program quits I guess I need to know how to make it go back to the displaymenu without quitting. hopefully I have explained it well enough to get some help with my problem.

here is my code so far:

```
def menu(): 
    while True:
        try:
            print(" Hello, and welcome to the integer fun menu\n")
            num=int(input(" to begin please enter in a non-negative integer--->")), print("\n")
            break 
        except ValueError:
            print("\nThat is not a valid response please input another\n")
def displaymenu():
    while True:
        try:
            choice=int(input("""Thank you now please choose from the options listed below.\n 
                      1. Enter a new integer
                      2. Find all evens, odds and zeroes
                      3. sum up all numbers in the integer
                      4. Quit \n""")) 
            if choice == 1:
                menu() 
                break
            elif choice == 2:
                Evens()
                break
            elif choice == 3:
                Sums()
                break
            elif choice == 4:
                break
            else:
                print("I do not understand please choose again")
                displaymenu()
        except ValueError:
            print("I do not understand please choose again")
    exit





menu()
displaymenu()
```

Comment: Awesome thank you for the assistance, you have no clue how long I tried to get that work. I tried if statements so many times haha anyway thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling displaymenu() only once.

You have to call it from menu() everytime you get a new number.

Modified:

```
def menu(): 
        while True:
            try:
                print(" Hello, and welcome to the integer fun menu\n")
                num=int(input(" to begin please enter in a non-negative integer--->")), print("\n")
                displaymenu()
                break 
            except ValueError:
                print("\nThat is not a valid response please input another\n")
    def displaymenu():
        while True:
            try:
                choice=int(input("""Thank you now please choose from the options listed below.\n 
                          1. Enter a new integer
                          2. Find all evens, odds and zeroes
                          3. sum up all numbers in the integer
                          4. Quit \n""")) 
                if choice == 1:
                    menu() 
                    break
                elif choice == 2:
                    Evens()
                    break
                elif choice == 3:
                    Sums()
                    break
                elif choice == 4:
                    break
                else:
                    print("I do not understand please choose again")
                    displaymenu()
            except ValueError:
                print("I do not understand please choose again")
        exit
    menu()
```